# Laravel - Leave status is giving wrong result in chartjs BarChart

Tags: laravel, chart.js

In my Laravel-5.8 Application I am displaying Employee Leave Status on BarChart using ChartJs

Controller

```
public function leave()
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;

     // All Leave Requests
    $allEmployeeLeaves = HrLeaveRequest::select(DB::raw("COUNT(leave_status) as count"))
        ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
        ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
        ->orderBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"), 'ASC')
        ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"))
        ->get()->toArray();
    $allEmployeeLeaves = array_column($allEmployeeLeaves, 'count');     

//Approved Leaves
    $approvedLeaves = HrLeaveRequest::select(DB::raw("COUNT(leave_status) as count"))
        ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
        ->where('leave_status', '=', 4)
        ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
        ->orderBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"), 'ASC')
        ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"))
        ->get()->toArray();
    $approvedLeaves = array_column($approvedLeaves, 'count'); 

// Rejected Leaves
    $rejectedLeaves = HrLeaveRequest::select(DB::raw("COUNT(leave_status) as count"))
        ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
        ->where('leave_status', 3)
        ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
        ->orderBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"), 'ASC')
        ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"))
        ->get()->toArray();
    $rejectedLeaves = array_column($rejectedLeaves, 'count');          


    return view('leave-default')
            ->with('allEmployeeLeaves',json_encode($allEmployeeLeaves,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK))
            ->with('approvedLeaves',json_encode($approvedLeaves,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK))
            ->with('rejectedLeaves',json_encode($rejectedLeaves,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));       
}
```

From the Query Above I want to display a Bar Chart for:

1. All Leave Requests
2. Approved Leave
3. Rejected Leave

Actually when leave_status = 3, it is rejected leaves and leave_status = 4 is approved leave.

View

```
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="chart">
              <canvas id="leaveBarChart" style="min-height: 250px; height: 450px; max-height: 250px; max-width: 100%;"></canvas>
            </div>
          </div>

<script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    var month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var data_all_leaves = <?php echo $allEmployeeLeaves; ?>;
    var data_approved_leaves = <?php echo $approvedLeaves; ?>;
    var data_rejected_leaves = <?php echo $rejectedLeaves; ?>;


    var barChartData = {
        labels: month,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'All Leave Requests',
            backgroundColor: "#f56954",
            data: data_all_leaves
        }, {
            label: 'Approved Leaves',
            backgroundColor: "#00a65a",
            data: data_approved_leaves
        }, {
            label: 'Rejected Leaves',
            backgroundColor: "#f39c12",
            data: data_rejected_leaves
        }]
    };


    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("leaveBarChart").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: barChartData,
            options: {
                elements: {
                    rectangle: {
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        borderSkipped: 'bottom'
                    }
                },
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio     : true,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Monthly Leave Status'
                }
            }
        });


    };
</script>
```

Displayed Result

[image: leave bar chart]

I expected the Barchart to display:

All Leaves, Rejected Leaves and Approved Leave. However, I have these three (3) observations.

1. The chart only display All Leave, which is 2. This comprise of Approved Leave (1) and Rejected Leave (1). It didn't display Approved and Rejected Leaves.
2. All the Leave are in May, but it put them in January
3. The Leave counts on the BarChart are in decimal places (1.00, 1.10 ...) instaed of 1, 2 ...

How do I corrected all these?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your bars may be present in the chart but actually hidden because the `yAxis` starts at 1. Therefore you should add the following `scales.yAxes.ticks` definition inside the chart `options`. This will also solve the problem with the decimals in the `yAxis` tick labels.

```
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        stepSize: 1
      }
    }]
  }
  ...
```

Make sure also, that the position of the values in individual `datasets.data` arrays is the same as the corresponding label in the `labels` array. That way, the bars should appear at the correct position also.